# How to handle multiple regular expression in same string C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to handel multiple different situation in the same string with regular expression. But when i'm using the code under, only the last expression will work. so dobbel stars(**) will be posted like it is, but underline(_) will be handled by the `replace()`function.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
 public ActionResult Comment(Models.CommentModel s)
    {
        Regex fat = new Regex(@"\*\*(.*?)\*\*");
        Regex italic = new Regex(@"_(.*?)_");

       s.comment = fat.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s.comment), "<b>$1</b>");
       s.comment = italic.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s.comment), "<i>$1</i>");

       var db = new WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationDbContext();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (file != null)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(s);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Comment");
        }
        return View(s);
    }
```

To decrease the amount of code I have tried to merge `italic`and `fat`string together like this: `Regex(@"\*\*(.*?)\*\*|_(.*?)_");` but then i have another problem, how can Regex know the difference?

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags Why are you trying to parse html with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are encoding the same html *twice* :

```
   // comment : sampletext **bold** _italic_ stuffsss

   s.comment = fat.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s.comment), "<b>$1</b>");
   // comment : sampletext <b>bold</b> _italic_ stuffsss

   s.comment = italic.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s.comment), "<i>$1</i>");
   // comment : sampletext &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; <i>italic</i> stuffsss
```

Simply encoding it once, when you are done with the replacing :

```
Regex fat = new Regex(@"\*\*(.*?)\*\*"); // btw this is called `bold` not `fat`
Regex italic = new Regex(@"_(.*?)_");

s.comment = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s.comment)

s.comment = fat.Replace(s.comment, "<b>$1</b>");
s.comment = italic.Replace(s.comment, "<i>$1</i>");
```

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly, the only change i had to make were the last line, it needed to be above the `replace()` lines to work.

Comment: you are right. Indeed, it has to be above the replace, as any angle-bracket will be encoding which is not what we want.